# C# method to scale values?

Tags: c#, .net, math

I have a value range from 0 to 255.

There is a method that returns an array with a min and max values within this range, i.e: 13, 15, 20, 27, 50 ... 240
where 13 is the min and 240 is the max

I need to scale these values so that 13 becomes 0 and 240 becomes 255 and scale all the other values between them proportionally.

Is there any C# method that does that?

thanks!

Comment: Are we to assume that you're looking to get an array of floats out?

Comment: yes, I forgot to mention that... The method would receive that array and return a new one scaled.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use this formula

```
y=mx+c
```

where `m = (255-0)/(244-13)` and `c= -13*m`

So you have to just transform the array as such

```
 public double[] GetScaling(double[] arr, double min, double max)
{
    double m = (max-min)/(arr.Max()-arr.Min());
    double c = min-arr.Min()*m;
    var newarr=new double[arr.Length];
    for(int i=0; i< newarr.Length; i++)
       newarr[i]=m*arr[i]+c;
    return newarr;
}
```

Comment: Instead of specifiying 244 and 13, you should really retrieve the actual min and max of the specified array.

Comment: @ccomet, that should be trivial

Comment: thanks!! worked perfectly! But double m = (255-0)/(244-13); returns an int, it should be converted to double...

Comment: You should not calculate m once, but instead use it in each index. That avoids using floats, you can do all math using only ints, which avoids all the related rounding problems (e.g. rounding 4.9997 to 4).

Answer (score 11):

To scale value in a range (minScale, maxScale)

```
private double Scale(int value , int min, int max, int minScale, int maxScale)
{
  double scaled = minScale + (double)(value - min)/(max-min) * (maxScale - minScale);
  return scaled;
}
```

To find min and max from incoming array

```
var min = Array.Min();
var max = Array.Max();
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using .NET 3.5, then LINQ can easily obtain the minimum and maximum values from any `IEnumerable<T>` object, which an array is.

```
int[] values = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, ... 255 };

int minValue = values.Min();
int maxValue = values.Max();
```

If you're looking for something to scale the whole array...

```
public static int[] Scale(int[] values, int scaledMin, int scaledMax)
{
    int minValue = values.Min();
    int maxValue = values.Max();

    float scale = (float)(scaledMax - scaledMin) / (float)(maxValue - minValue);
    float offset = minValue * scale - scaledMin;

    int[] output = new int[values.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = (int)Math.Round(values[i] * scale - offset, 0);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: He knows the max and min. He wants to transform the values in the middle so that they become from 0 to 255.

Comment: @Daniel: it's good practice to construct reusable methods whether he knows the values or not.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: My comment was only appliable for a first version of the question, which just said how you can find the maximum and the minimum, and nothing about scaling. Interestingly, this version has only existed in my dreams: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2675221/revisions

Comment: Edits within 5 minutes of posting are not recorded. But worry not! I saw the "dream" version you saw.